# Send and receive files via bluetoothctl on Debian jessie

Tags: debian, bluetooth

I have already successfully paired and connected to my smartphone device. Now when i send files from my phone to my Laptop the files will not be sent. How can i send and receive files using `bluetoothctl` on Debian 8.7?
Can any one give me some source for reading, i can't find much about bluetoothctl on internet.

Answer (score 5):

The `bluetoothctl` is used only to control your bluetooth devices , to transfer your file you should use another tools for example [`obexftp`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/obexftp) :

```
apt install obexftp
```

[`man obexftp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/obexftp) :

```
obexftp is used to access files on mobile equipment, i.e. cell phones. 
With obexftpd you can transfer files between any computers using IrDA, 
Bluetooth and TCP/IP
```

> To get the file `bar` from directory `foo` from the first bluetooth device:

```
obexftp -b -c foo -g bar
```

or using the MAC_Address :

```
obexftp -b MAC_address -g bar
```

> To send the file `bar` to directory `foo` with device on first serial port:

```
obexftp -t /dev/ttyS0 -c foo -p bar
```

Or using the MAC_Address :

```
obexftp -b MAC_address -p bar
```

Option:

```
-p source, --put source
-g source, --get source
-b device, --bluetooth device
-t device, --tty device
```

Comment: Running the commands of `obexftp` doesn't do anything. It prints that its browsing the MAC_Address Device, but cant find and connect to it. I have bluwtoothctl on and my device connected to my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning receiving files, roughly the following seems to work (following the instructions on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=146328). Yet quite unstable in my setup:

- Make sure bluetoothd is started in compatibility mode, I did this by a hacky `sudo systemctl stop bluetoothctl.service; sudo bluetoothd -C`
- Start obexpushd: `sudo obexpushd -d` (in debug mode, so you see if something happens)
- In `bluetoothctl`:

  - power on
  - pairable on
  - discoverable on

Again, this, at least in my case is not very reliable and enabling/disabling bluetooth and redoing the procedure sometimes works.